# dbms_metadata.get_ddl ...the DDL produce throws a syntax error

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to re-create a table from one of our development database  using dbms_metadata.get_ddl function in oracle. e.g.

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','ogaPatch2892_TAB','XVIEWMGR')from dual;
```

It does produce the DDL that I need however running it produces an error

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Below is the DDL sytax:

```
CREATE TABLE "XVIEWMGR"."ogaPatch2892_TAB" OF XMLTYPE
PCTFREE 10
PCTUSED 40
INITRANS 1
MAXTRANS 255
NOCOMPRESS
LOGGING
STORAGE (INITIAL 65536
         NEXT 1048576
         MINEXTENTS 1
         MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
         PCTINCREASE 0
         FREELISTS 1
         FREELIST GROUPS 1
         BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
         FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
         CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "TBSDATA"
VARRAY "XMLEXTRA"."NAMESPACES"
   STORE AS BASICFILE LOB "NAMESPACES2895_L" (
   ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
   CHUNK 8192
   RETENTION
   CACHE
   STORAGE (INITIAL 65536
            NEXT 1048576
            MINEXTENTS 1
            MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0
            FREELISTS 1
            FREELIST GROUPS 1
            BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT))
VARRAY "XMLEXTRA"."EXTRADATA"
   STORE AS BASICFILE LOB "EXTRADATA2894_L" (
   ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
   CHUNK 8192
   RETENTION
   CACHE
   STORAGE (INITIAL 65536
            NEXT 1048576
            MINEXTENTS 1
            MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0
            FREELISTS 1
            FREELIST GROUPS 1
            BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT))
VARRAY "XMLDATA"."SYS_XDBPD$"
   STORE AS BASICFILE LOB "SYS_XDBPD$2893_L" (
   ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
   CHUNK 8192
   RETENTION
   CACHE
   STORAGE (INITIAL 65536
            NEXT 1048576
            MINEXTENTS 1
            MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
            PCTINCREASE 0
            FREELISTS 1
            FREELIST GROUPS 1
            BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do as below. No need to specify the storage paramaters. Oracle will automatically pick up the default values set when database would had been installed or set by DBA.

```
CREATE TABLE XVIEWMGR.ogaPatch2892_TAB OF XMLTYPE;
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right just wanted to make sure that corresponding lob segment are created with those name encapsulated in double quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Eva You can set Storage parameter false while executing dbms_metadata.get_ddl() so that ouput should exclude the storage paramater. Read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_1_dbms_metadata.htm